# ¿Cómo le paso una variable de Javascript a un button para que haga scroll hasta un ancla determinado?

Tags: javascript, html, botón, html-select, enlaces-ancla

Atención, tengo dos selects, el segundo dependiente del primero con JS, y luego tengo el input, al que quiero pasarle como href la misma variante que saca el segundo select, para que vaya al id indicado.

```js
var subcategory = {
  "Tracto alimentario y metabolismo": ["Antieméticos y antinauseosos", "Terapia biliar y hepática", "Laxantes", "Fármacos usados en diabetes", "Otros productos para el tracto alimentario y metabolismo"],
  "Sangre y órganos hematopoyéticos": ["Agentes antitrombóticos","Antihemorrágicos"],
  "Sistema cardiovascular": ["Antihipertensivos", "Diuréticos", "Agentes que actúan sobre el sistema renina-angiotensina", "Agentes modificadores de los lípidos"],
  "Dermatológicos": ["Preparados dermatológicos con corticosteroides"],
  "Sistema genitourinario y hormonas sexuales": ["Hormonas sexuales y moduladores genitales"],
  "Preparados hormonales sistémicos, excluyendo hormonas sexuales e insulinas": ["Hormonas hipotalámicas e hipofisarias y sus análogos", "Homeostasis del calcio"],
  "Antiinfecciosos para uso sistémico": ["Antibacterianos para uso sistémico", "Antimicóticos para uso sistémico", "Antimicobacterias", "Antivirales de uso sistémico", "Sueros inmunes e inmunoglobulinas"],
  "Antineoplásicos e inmunomoduladores": ["Agentes antineoplásicos", "Terapia endocrina", "Inmunoestimulantes", "Inmunosupresores"],
  "Sistema musculoesquelético": ["Preparados antigotosos", "Otros fármacos para alteraciones del sistema musculoesqueléticos"],
  "Sistema nervioso": ["Antiepilépticos", "Antiparkinsonianos", "Psicolépticos", "Psicoanalépticos", "Otros fármacos que actúan sobre el sistema nervioso"],
  "Antiparasitarios, insecticidas y repelentes": [],
  "Sistema respiratorio": ["Agentes contra padecimientos obstructivos de las vías respiratorias", "Otros productos para el sistema respiratorio"],
  "Órganos de los sentidos": ["Oftalmológicos"],
  "Varios": ["Todo el resto de los grupos terapéuticos", "Productos radiofármacos para diagnóstico", "Productos radiofármacos terapéuticos"]
}
function makeSubmenu(value) {
  if(value.length==0) 
    document.getElementById("categorySelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var citiesOptions = "";
    for(categoryId in subcategory[value]) {
      citiesOptions+="<option>"+subcategory[value][categoryId]+"</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("categorySelect").innerHTML = citiesOptions;
  }
 }
 
function displaySelected() {
  var country = document.getElementById("category").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("categorySelect").value;
  alert(country+"\n"+city);
}

function resetSelection() {
  document.getElementById("category").selectedIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById("categorySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
}


$(function() {
    $("#myContent").addClass(categorySelect);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <label for="categoria"><h3>Categoria</h3></label>

           <select id="category" size="1" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)" v-model="categoria" title="categoria" name="categoria" style="font: 400 13.3333px Arial; width: 90%; float:left; padding: 3px;">
               <option value="" disabled selected title="Seleccione categoría">Seleccione categoría</option>
               <option>Tracto alimentario y metabolismo</option>
               <option>Sangre y órganos hematopoyéticos</option>
               <option>Sistema cardiovascular</option>
               <option>Dermatológicos</option>
               <option>Sistema genitourinario y hormonas sexuales</option>
               <option>Preparados hormonales sistémicos, excluyendo hormonas sexuales e insulinas</option>  <option>Antiinfecciosos para uso sistémico</option>   
               <option>Antineoplásicos e inmunomoduladores</option>   
               <option>Sistema musculoesquelético</option>   
               <option>Sistema nervioso</option>   
               <option>Antiparasitarios, insecticidas y repelentes</option>   
               <option>Sistema respiratorio</option> 
               <option>Órganos de los sentidos</option>  
               <option>Varios</option>  
           </select>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
         <label for="especialidad"><h3>Especialidad</h3></label>
           <select id="categorySelect" size="1" v-model="especialidad" title="especialidad" name="especialidad"  style="font: 400 13.3333px Arial; width: 90%; float: left; padding: 3px;">
               <option value="" disabled selected title="Seleccione especialidad">Seleccione especialidad</option>
               <option></option>
           </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:right; padding-right: 43px;">
    <input title="botón buscar" type="button" value="BUSCAR" onclick="window.location.href='#myContent'" class="btn" style="padding: 5px 10px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px;">
</div>
```

La última función es un intento de sacar el mismo texto con otro nombre, pero nanai!